# Scope <style> only to that specific div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I encapsulate `<style>` inside a `<div>` only to that `<div>`?
The content inside `<div class="test">` will come from database with predefined `<style>` and other elements, so I can't add classes to elements and style those elements according to their class
First heading's color should be green while second heading's color should be red

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style>
            h1 {
                color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>This is a heading</h1>

        <div class="test">
            <style>
                h1 {
                    color: red;
                }
            </style>
            
            <h1>This is a heading inside div.test</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: be aware that `<style>` outside nof the head element is invalid HTML Markup. The scope attribute has been finally deprecated in 2019 by Mozilla while Chrome already deprecated it in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Just use combined selectors that contains the classes of the parent elements:

```css
h1 {
  color: purple;
}
.test1 h1 {
  color: red;
}
.test2 h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<div class="test1">
  <h1>This is a heading inside div .test1</h1>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <h1>This is a heading inside div .test2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is either give each h1 specific style names. So for your first header it would be:

```css
h1-1 {
   color: red;
}
```

However, this is very inefficient and not very professional. This is the most clean way of handling this:

```css
.test h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

What you are doing is selecting the parent class with `.test` and then selected the child class and apply the color red onto it.

Here is a code snippet to show how it works.

```css
.parent .child {
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<h1>This block is uncolored!</h1>

<div class="parent">
  <h1 class="child">
    This is colored red!
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would go as this: every user content from DB has single ID element that wraps it's content and then is mandatory to be included. That way you can encapsulate any style:

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<!-- random generated ID wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper-00123ABCFF">
  <div class="test">
    <style>
      #wrapper-00123ABCFF h1 {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>

    <h1>This is a heading inside div.test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper-AFFCC0023">
  <div class="test">
    <style>
      #wrapper-AFFCC0023 h1 {
        color: yellow;
      }
    </style>

    <h1>This is a heading inside div.test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If generating styles with CssLess it would be extra ease:

```
#wrapper-AFFCC0023 {
   /* ... User style */
}
```

otherwise you should use some regex to prefix any top level selectors with this user-specific selector